# -1 appears as 4294967295 with sprintf()

Tags: c

On my 64-bit Linux distribution, when I execute this code:

```
long x ;
char buf[80];
x = (long)-1 ;
sprintf( buf, "%ld", x) ;

printf( buf ) ;
```

I get 4294967295, which is 2^32 -1.

However, when I do:

```
long x ;
char buf[80];
x = (long)-1 ;
sprintf( buf, "%d", x) ;

printf( buf ) ;
```

I get -1, which is the proper result.

What makes this more confusing is that I've tried this on other systems and the first one outputs -1 there. What could be the issue here?

Comment: What type is x?

Comment: You're most likely hacking on the type system.

Comment: @self it's of type long

Comment: Note: `sprintf( buf, "%d", x);` --> "I get -1, which is the proper result." is incorrect.  `x` in this case is `long` and the specifier `"%d"` is for `int`.  The result is undefined behavior (UB).  It may  work as desired on a given platform but is fundamentally bad C code.

Comment: The first case is either not posted correctly or the platform is not compliant C.

Answer (score 1):

if x is an unsigned int\long that is what should happen since ~-1 (2s complement) is 2^32-1

Comment: It's not an unsigned long, it's just a long int.